# Identify NA's in sequence row-wise

Tags: r, na

I want to fill NA values in a sequence, which is row-wise, based on a condition. Please see example below.

```
ID | Observation 1 | Observation 2 | Observation 3 | Observation 4 | Observation 5
 A         NA              0               1             NA             NA
```

The condition is:

- all NA values before !NA values in the sequence should be left as NA;
- but all NAs after !NA values in the sequence should be tagged ("remove")

In the example above, NA value in Observation 1 should remain NA. However, the NA values in Observations 4 and 5 should be changed to "Remove".

Comment: What is the structure of your actual data? Please post a sample of it using `dput(name_of_object)`. Using the string `"remove"` as a flag will be problematic in a data.frame containing numeric data because you cannot mix numeric and non-numeric values within a given column.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. the object is a dataframe containing only numerical variables. I said remove just as an example, it can be any number as a flag.

Comment: I know you said row-wise, but are `observation 1`, `observation 2`, etc. separate columns, and you want to do this for each row of a data frame/table?

Comment: Yes, observation 1, observation 2... etc are separate columns. Its a transposed dataframe. And correct, I want to do this for the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the function:

```
replace.na <- function(r,val) {
  i <- is.na(r)
  j <- which(i)
  k <- which(!i)
  r[j[j > k[length(k)]]] <- val
  r
}
```

Then, assuming that you have a `data.frame` like so:

```
r <- data.frame(ID=c('A','B'),obs1=c(NA,1),obs2=c(0,NA),obs3=c(1,2),obs4=c(NA,3),obs5=c(NA,NA))
##  ID obs1 obs2 obs3 obs4 obs5
##1  A   NA    0    1   NA   NA
##2  B    1   NA    2    3   NA
```

We can `apply` the function over the rows for all numeric columns of `r`:

```
r[,-1] <- t(apply(r[,-1],1,replace.na,999))    
##  ID obs1 obs2 obs3 obs4 obs5
##1  A   NA    0    1  999  999
##2  B    1   NA    2    3  999
```

This treats `r[,-1]` as a `matrix` and the output of `apply` fills a `matrix`, which by default is filled by columns. Therefore, we have to transpose the resulting `matrix` before replacing the columns back into `r`.

Another way to call `replace.na` is:

```
r[,-1] <- do.call(rbind,lapply(data.frame(t(r[,-1])),replace.na,999))
```

Here, we transpose the numeric columns of `r` first and make that a `data.frame`. This makes each row of `r` a column in the list of columns that is the resulting data frame. Then use `lapply` over these columns to apply `replace.na` and `rbind` the results.

---

If you want to flag all `NA`'s after the first non-`NA`, then the function `replace.na` should be:

```
replace.na <- function(r,val) {
  i <- is.na(r)
  j <- which(i)
  k <- which(!i)
  r[j[j > k[1]]] <- val
  r
}
```

Applying it to the data:

```
r[,-1] <- do.call(rbind,lapply(data.frame(t(r[,-1])),replace.na,999))
##  ID obs1 obs2 obs3 obs4 obs5
##1  A   NA    0    1  999  999
##2  B    1  999    2    3  999
```

Comment: great @aichao... even i was trying something similar, but you did the job!

Comment: And if I would like to change obs2 to 999, what would be the solution r[j[j = k[length(k)]]] <- val ?

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful.

Comment: @User2321: the first version will only replace all `NA`'s after the **last** non-`NA` to the replacement value. So, for your data `r <- c(NA, 0, 1, NA, NA, 1)`, we get for `replace.na(r,5)` the result `[1] NA 0 1 NA NA 1`. That is, nothing is replaced since the last value in `r` is non-`NA`. The second version replaces all `NA`'s after the **first** non-`NA` to the replacement value. In that case, `replace.na(r,5)` gives `[1] NA 0 1 5 5 1`.