# how to recode omitted items after the last response different from omitted items before the last response

Tags: position

for each row, I need to re-code all two's after the last one or zero with different code. here is an example

`0 1 2 1 2 2`

`0 2 1 2 2 2`

`0 1 2 1 0 1`

`0 0 0 2 1 2`

For each row I want to re-code all 2 after the last 1 or 0 different from 2 before the last 1 or 0. can anyone show me with a simple example?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? Code snippet, language?

Comment: I have added an example, Please see above again

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer to my question in this page ([Identify NA's in sequence row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184721/identify-nas-in-sequence-row-wise)) 
i just manipulate it very little