# re-coding based on entry position

Tags: recode

For each row in my data, I want to re-code all "NA" after the last "1" or "0" different from "NA" before the last "1" or "0". Here is an example:

r <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,
              1,1,1,1,0,
              1,NA,1,1,1,
              1,0,1,1,1,
              1,1,1,NA,NA,
              1,1,0,NA,1,
              1,1,NA,NA,NA,
              1,NA,NA,NA,NA),ncol=5, nrow=8, byrow=T,
              dimnames= list(c("r1", "r2","r3","r4","r5","r6","r7","r8"), 
              c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5")))

Can anyone show me with a simple example?

Comment: for solution see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184721/identify-nas-in-sequence-row-wise)